# Table row border doesn't work in Firefox and Safari

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, tablerow

I wanted the table row to have a border on the bottom and top. The code below works in IE but not in Firefox or Safari! Kindly help!

HTML

```
 <tr class='TableRow'>
```

CSS

```
.TableRow{
   border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(167,167,167);
   border-top: 2px solid rgb(167,167,167);
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot set borders to table rows through CSS. But I will suggest you a workaround to this: Set the borders to the cells inside the row, and then use cellspacing="0".
Here is the CSS:

```
.TableRow td{
   border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(167,167,167);
   border-top: 2px solid rgb(167,167,167);
}
```

And a sample HTML would be:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="TableRow">
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The first row will be the one with borders.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: I tried your code and didn't show the border in any browser, including IE.

Comment: This only worked for me once I gave my `<table>` a CSS declaration of `border-collapse: separate`.

Answer (score 3):

Add `border-collapse:collapse` to the table then you can add border to the tr.

Example:

```
table.myTable{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

table.myTable tr{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this fix your problem?

```
tr.TableRow td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(167,167,167);
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(167,167,167);
}
```

It will add a border to all of the table data within any rows with the class `TableRow`. Adding the `tr.` at the start is good practice, as I assume you'll only be using this class with table row.

If you are applying this to multiple rows- you may also want to add `border-collapse:collapse;` which will collapse the borders into a single border.